# Loading ESRI raster in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: raster, mapbox-gl-js, esri

Is it possible to load ESRI raster tiles from a tiles.arcgis.com service? In this [mapbox demo](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/map-tiles/), the line that specifies the basemap tiling service (from Stamen, in this case) is this:

```
'tiles': [
   'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
],
```

When I edit the fiddle example, however, and try to substitute [a tileset I'm interested in using](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?basemapUrl=https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/QcN4ko50whTktDF1/arcgis/rest/services/Ortho_Midland2020_0520and0521/MapServer?cacheKey=96e2b57f57421b7f), it doesn't seem to work:

```
'tiles': [
'https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/QcN4ko50whTktDF1/arcgis/rest/services/Ortho_Midland2020_0520and0521/MapServer/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg'
],
```

I was able to get direct access to some of the individual tiles, [like this](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/QcN4ko50whTktDF1/arcgis/rest/services/Ortho_Midland2020_0520and0521/MapServer/tile/15/11951/8699), but can't seem to get the URL string right. [Here is a page with metadata](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/QcN4ko50whTktDF1/arcgis/rest/services/Ortho_Midland2020_0520and0521/MapServer?cacheKey=96e2b57f57421b7f), as well as the start and end tiles for each zoom level.

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong with that URL string? I've also changed the initial zoom and x/y to be relevant to the dataset:

center: [-84.39479, 43.820487],
zoom: 11

Here is [a fiddle that I've been trying out various URLs in](https://jsfiddle.net/alejandrokennedy/56nt4328/31/). I would super appreciate pointers about how to format the ESRI tileset URL for use in mapbox gl js. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- First, the URLs should not have `.jpg` on the end.
- Second, ArcGIS online URLs are z/y/x, not z/x/y

So the correct URL is:

`https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/QcN4ko50whTktDF1/arcgis/rest/services/Ortho_Midland2020_0520and0521/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}`

Updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/stevage/z9nao1cv/4/